# Most efficient way (according RAM/CPU consumption) to add elements from one ArrayList to another ArrayList to specific position

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists **A** and **B**. I need to combine this two ArrayLists. Put all elements from  ArrayList_**B** to ArrayList_**A** at specific places.

Element composition in the  ArrayList_**A** should looks like:
a1b1a2b2a3b3....

But do this at the most efficiency way, as I can.

*Rules*: Do not change create ArrayList_**B**.

As you can see, most efficient way in my example is Method2. But it's still very slow for huge ArrayList's.

***Please, suggest the most efficient way how to do that.*** Thanks for your attention:).

public class Solution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Method1();
    Method2();
    Method3();

}

private static void Method3() {
    ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> b = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        a.add("a" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        b.add("b" + i);
    }

    ArrayList<Object> aa = new ArrayList<>(a);
    a.ensureCapacity(2*aa.size());
    a.clear();

    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();


    for (int i = 0; i<b.size();i++) {
        a.add(aa.get(i));
        a.add(b.get(i));
    }
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(time2 - time1);
}

private static void Method2() {
    ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> b = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        a.add("a" + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        b.add("b" + i);
    }

    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int size = a.size();
    a.add(b.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        a.add(a.get(i));
        a.add(b.get(i));
    }
    a.subList(1, size).clear();

    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(time2 - time1);

}

private static void Method1() {
    ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> b = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        a.add("a" + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 15); i++) {
        b.add("b" + i);
    }

    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    a.add(1, b.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < b.size(); i++) {
        a.add((2 * i + 1), b.get(i));
    }

    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(time2 - time1);
}
```

}

Comment: I would create a copy of a, clear it and build a again. Make sure the capacity is right from the start instead of having to grow it. You can use `ensureCapacity(size*2)` I would also ensure the code has been warmed up, running it repeatedly and ignore the first 2 seconds of testing that piece of code.

Comment: I wonder how many times `Math.pow(2,15)` will be calculated.

Comment: Peter Lawrey, thank for your advice, I will try it letter. But for instance, ArrayList ***A*** I have as default list and ArrayList ***B***  as incoming parameter. May be you have any Idea how it cam be done more efficiency without create a new list?

Comment: Method3 by Peter Lawrey faster than Method 2! Maybe someone has any other ideas?

Comment: `Math.pow(2, 15) == 1 << 15`

Comment: Thanks all for yours answers!

One things separate from best solution is how to do that without creating a new ArrayList (in the Peter's answer is a copy of ArrayList A). Like in the Method 2, but more efficiency. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer is probably the best.  However, if you are doing this a lot, perhaps define your own class.  Skeleton code, perhaps buggy, *assumes that your two input arrays a and b never change, you never want to change the combined list after creation*, etc...:

```
public class DualList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
   final List<E> a; 
   final List<E> b;

   public DualList(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
      this.a = a;  this.b = b;
   }

   public E get(int idx) {
      int half = idx >> 1;
      if ((idx & 1) == 1)
         return this.b.get(half);
      else
         return this.a.get(half);
   }

   // not sure what else you need or want to override...
}
```

This will obviously be way way quicker "creating" the combined list, since it does next to nothing, but this will be a little bit slower every time you call `get()` to retrieve an element.  So final decision depends on just how may times you are calling `get()`.

Comment: Thank you, it also useful, I will put it in my knowledge base! :)